# How to calculate $\arctan(\sqrt3-2)$ to be $-15°$ by hand?

Tags: trigonometry

Not approximately, but precisely, and what does one need to know to be able to do that?

For instance, I know that $\tan(45°)$ gives the incline of a line which encloses $45°$ with the $x$-axis, namely $1$, therefore $\arctan(1)=45°$ or $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Is there a way to use this relation?

Regards

Comment: You've mixed up tan and arctan. It's $\tan(45°)=1$ and $\arctan(1)=45°$ (or, better, $\pi/4$).

Comment: $\tan\dfrac{\alpha}{2}=\dfrac{1-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}$. Now let $\alpha=30^\circ$.

Answer (score 6):

Take a 30-60-90 triangle, with sides $1,\sqrt{3},2$.   Extend the side of length $\sqrt{3}$ by an extra two units.  That gives a $15-75-90$ triangle whose short sides are 1 and $2+\sqrt{3}$

Comment: How did you derive that? Can it be done for arbitrary angles?

Comment: An isosceles triangle, with two sides equal to 2, and one angle equal to 150 degrees.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can go the other way. That's easier.

$\tan 30^{\circ} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$

Let $t = \tan 15^{\circ}$.

So $\displaystyle \frac{2t}{1-t^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$

Solving,

$t^2 + 2\sqrt 3 t - 1 = 0$

$\displaystyle t = -\frac{-2\sqrt 3 + \sqrt{12+4}}{2}$ (only admissible root)

$t = 2 -\sqrt 3$

(edited as the question seems to have been amended to ask for $\tan (-15^{\circ})$:

$\tan (-15^{\circ}) = -\tan 15^{\circ} = \sqrt 3 - 2$

Answer (score 2):

You can use
$$
\tan(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{\tan\alpha-\tan\beta}{1+\tan\alpha\tan\beta}
$$
with $\alpha=45^\circ$ and $\beta=60^\circ$, so $\tan45^\circ=1$ and $\tan60^\circ=\sqrt{3}$:
$$
\tan(-15^\circ)=\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}}=\frac{(1-\sqrt{3})^2}{1-3}
=\frac{1-2\sqrt{3}+3}{-2}=\sqrt{3}-2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another way.
$$2-\sqrt{3}=\frac{(\sqrt{3}-1)(\sqrt{3}-1)}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{1+\sqrt{3}}$$

Now we have 
$$\arctan \left(\frac{a-b}{1+ab}\right)=\arctan a-\arctan b$$

So 
$$\arctan 2-\sqrt{3}=\arctan \sqrt{3}-\arctan 1=60^{\circ}-45^{\circ}=15^{\circ}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The angle occurs in the dodecagon, which is a composition of triangles and squares.  This gives you a coordinate system, from which ye find

sin(15) = (sqrt (3)+1)/sqrt(2)
cos(15) = (sqrt (3)-1)/sqrt(2)

Whence the ratio is (sqrt(3)-1)̃²/(sqrt(3)+1)(sqrt(3)-1) = 2-sqrt(3).

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt3-2=\cot30^\circ-\csc30^\circ=\dfrac{\cos30^\circ-1}{\sin30^\circ}=\dfrac{-2\sin^215^\circ}{2\sin15^\circ\cos15^\circ}=-\tan15^\circ=\tan(-15^\circ)$$

Now use $-90^\circ<\arctan x<90^\circ$